# How important is "or die" in a mysql statement with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, die

I've written a lot of my code already, but now I'm starting to question - how important is the statement such as:

```
or die(mysql_error());
```

In all my of queries?

I have it almost nowhere at the moment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd actually suggest not using this error in production because it stops the execution of the page right there. You'd want a more graceful exit for your users.

So in this specific case, you can do

`or handle_error();`

Where `handle_error()` is a method that you'd implement to gracefully exit for your users.

Comment: Gotcha.  If there is an error, and it doesn't execute properly, the data the program is expecting will NOT be there, and my code is set up to handle that situation, so in this case - there should be no problem right?

Comment: From what you've described, you should be OK. However you handled not expected data, but have you handled a socket timeout for mysql connections for example?